# Waiting on main thread for callback methods

Tags: multithreading, scala, concurrency

I am very new to Scala and following the Scala Book Concurrency section (from docs.scala-lang.org). Based off of the example they give in the book, I wrote a very simple code block to test using Futures:

```
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object Main {
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val a = Future{Thread.sleep(10*100); 42}
    a.onComplete {
      case Success(x) => println(a)
      case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000)
  }
}
```

When compiled and run, this properly prints out:

> Future(Success(42))

to the console. I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why the `Thread.sleep()` call comes after the onComplete callback method. Intuitively, at least to me, would be calling `Thread.sleep()` before the callback so by the time the main thread gets to the `onComplete` method `a` is assigned a value. If I move the `Thread.sleep()` call to before `a.onComplete`, nothing prints to the console. I'm probably overthinking this but any help clarifying would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well you can add `onComplete` after the `sleep` but you would need another sleep or better an `Await` to see the output.

Comment: Well because `onComplete` registers a callback, if the program finishes just after registering it then it won't have time to run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use the `Thread.sleep()` after registering the callback

```
    a.onComplete {
      case Success(x) => println(a)
      case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
    }
    Thread.sleep(5000)
```

then the thread that is executing the body of the future has the time to sleep one second and to set the `42` as the result of successful future execution. By that time (after approx. 1 second), the `onComplete` callback is already registered, so the thread calls this as well, and you see the output on the console.

The sequence is essentially:

- t = 0: Daemon thread begins the computation of `42`
- t = 0: Main thread creates and registers callback.
- t = 1: Daemon thread finishes the computation of `42`
- t = 1 + eps: Daemon thread finds the registered callback and invokes it with the result `Success(42)`.
- t = 5: Main thread terminates
- t = 5 + eps: program is stopped.

*(I'm using `eps` informally as a placeholder for some reasonably small time interval; `+ eps` means "almost immediately thereafter".)*

If you swap the `a.onComplete` and the outer `Thread.sleep` as in

```
    Thread.sleep(5000)
    a.onComplete {
      case Success(x) => println(a)
      case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
    }
```

then the thread that is executing the body of the future will compute the result `42` after one second, but it would not see any registered callbacks (it would have to wait four more seconds until the callback is created and registered on the main thread). But once 5 seconds have passed, the main thread registers the callback and exits immediately. Even though by that time it has the chance to know that the result `42` has already been computed, the main thread does not attempt to execute the callback, because it's none of its business (that's what the threads in the execution context are for). So, right after registering the callback, the main thread exits immediately. With it, all the daemon threads in the thread pool are killed, and the program exits, so that you don't see anything in the console.

The usual sequence of events is roughly this:

- t = 0: Daemon thread begins the computation of `42`
- t = 1: Daemon thread finishes the computation of `42`, but cannot do anything with it.
- t = 5: Main thread creates and registers the callback
- t = 5 + eps: Main thread terminates, daemon thread is killed, program is stopped.

so that there is (almost) no time when the daemon thread could wake up, find the callback, and invoke it.

Comment: What does "eps" stand for here?

Comment: [epsilon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epsilon#Symbol) - kinda-sorta referring to "an infinitesimally small positive quantity", but without the "infinitesimal" part: basically, I mean just some very small time period that is unlikely to interleave with anything that some other thread is doing. It's hand-wavy, and does not have any formal meaning here.

Comment: Thanks, I figured it meant something along those lines, wasn't sure if that was an actual measurement of a super small time interval or just a placeholder.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of things in Scala are functions and don't necessarily look like it. The argument to `onComplete` is one of those things. What you've written is

```
a.onComplete {
  case Success(x) => println(a)
  case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
}
```

What that translates to after all the Scala magic is effectively (modulo `PartialFunction` shenanigans)

```
a.onComplete({ value =>
  value match {
    case Success(x) => println(a)
    case Failure(e) => e.printStackTrace
  }
})
```

`onComplete` isn't actually doing any work. It's just setting up a function that will be called at a later date. So we want to do that as soon as we can, and the Scala scheduler (specifically, the `ExecutionContext`) will invoke our callback at its convenience.